# How to bypass a file upload script when a file is not uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload

I have a form that sends text inputs and sometimes files. I am having an issue for situations where files aren't being  uploaded. Currently, if a file is not included in the form submission, I get the following error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadedFile

The error is directly related to this line of code:

`$file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);`

I know what the error is saying. My question is can I predefine the file count at 0 for when a file isn't uploaded in javascript that can be translated to PHP. Or is there a way to check if it is set before running `$file_count`?

However, there are more occurrences throughout the script. Would I just put an if statement right after the function declaration?

```
public function upload() {

    $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
    $results = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        //echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";

        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));        

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            return 0;
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                $results[] = basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
```

Comment: `if ( !isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']['error']) ) { // then you have a file uploaded`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there any advantage to doing it this way opposed to checking if it is not empty?

Comment: isset will throw an warning if it does not exist, use !empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if there is a file attachment using empty

```
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {
```

empty does not generate a notice or warning if it finds nothing, like isset or count

Comment: Are you saying to wrap all children element of the upload function in that if statement?

Comment: from manual ... No warning is generated by empty if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.